# Querying a Date range in django for the past 10 days

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to query a date range in django, but I'm not getting the expected results.

I have a coupon model that has an end_date Field and I'd like to filter for all coupons that are expiring in the next 10 days. My model field looks like this:

```
end_date = models.DateField()
```

Here is what I have tried. Any help is appreciated:

```
start = datetime.now()
end = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=10)
expiring_coupons = Coupon.models.filter(end_date__range=(start, end))
```

Comment: What results are you getting, and why are they not what you expected?

Comment: I have end dates that fall in that range but are getting filtered out. For example, May 31st gets filtered out. I'm currently looking into if the datetime field vs datefield makes a difference/ stepping through the code.

Comment: May 31st is in 12 days, so I would expect it to be filtered out if you use `timedelta(days=10)`. If `end_date` is a `DateField`, it would be more consistent to use `date.today()` instead of `datetime.now()`.

Comment: I thought range was meant to capture that whole date range? For example, I need to filter for discounts that are expiring today, tomorrow, the day after that, etc. up until 10 days from today.

Comment: For example when I use 20 days it still gets filtered out -- I see how it get filtered out for 10 days though.

Comment: How are you testing the querysets? If you change the time delta from 10 days to 20 days are you sure you have restarted the server so that you are not running the old code?

Comment: I can take it from here; I just have to step through the code. I'm actually getting the data from elastic search, if that makes a difference:  end_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='end_date')